# How to interact with a contract that requires a uint256 value? The input I want to give is "5"

Tags: contract-invocation

I have the following contract function. I want to input 5, but it requires it in the format **uint256**. How do I represent this in uint256?

And is there a way to interact with this contract function without going through metamask, but via a command line and just my private key?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

uint256 stands for "unsigned integer". 256 stands for the size. (78 digits)

So you can represent number from 0 to 2^256-1.

You don't have to convert the number to uint256, it is already a uint256 type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can interact with Ethereum smart contract functions using a command line interface and your private key through tools like Remix, Geth or Truffle, (i use hardhat). These tools allow you to deploy and interact with smart contracts on the Ethereum network.

You must have:
-the ABI of the contract
-the address of the contract
-also choose a node to connect or a provider

Comment: I'm looking at other transactions from other people that used the same function and they have the following: Function: ClaimCheckpoint(uint256 whichCheckpoint) --MethodID: 0x9c8dbcc5 --
[0]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005 --- The 5 with a bunch of leading zeros. I'm guessing I don't input that, but just 5?

Comment: it is because the size of a memory slot is 32 bytes, even if you store just the "5" value. Everytime you see "uint" just store the basic value you want and it knows to do the stuff. (if you use hardhat for example)